# Flexbox inside a table with a minimum height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like have a table which resembles a calendar (I need to use a table markup, unfortunately). It consists of rows being weeks and every row has 7 cells - days. A single cell need to contain:

- a tasks list (from 0 to n entries)
- a number indicating which number of day it is.

The number has to be always at the very bottom of the cell, no matter if there are any tasks or not. Tasks, if there are any, have to start at the top of the cell. The cell also needs to have a minimum height, due to how the designs look. There should be no scrollbar for the cell contents.

I've created a simple solution for that using flex and setting `height` for `<td>`s (you can see a oversimplified version in the snippet below), however it works beautifully in Chrome, IE and Edge, but doesn't work in Firefox.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  height: 45px;
}

.task {
  display: block;
}

.day-contents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="day-contents">
        <div class="tasks">
          <a href="#" class="task">Task 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="task">Task 2</a>
        </div>
        <span class="day">1</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="day-contents">
        <div class="tasks">
          <a href="#" class="task">Task 3</a>
        </div>
        <span class="day">2</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="day-contents">
        <div class="tasks"></div>
        <span class="day">3</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It seems like Firefox "forgets" to resize the first cell to match the height of its contents. If I remove `height: 100%;` from the `.day-contents` then Firefox now resizes the first cell, but now only the tallest one fulfills the positioning specification I described in the second paragraph.

Is this a bug in Firefox or am I accidentally using some kind of undefined behavior that browsers can interpret as they wish? Is there any workaround for this I can use?